# How do you make jest.mock(file) dynamic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-router, enzyme

I am trying to mock react-router-dom like so

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useLocation: () => ({
        pathname: '/random/path',
    }),
}))
```

this works and is all good but I want to change the pathname for different tests so that I can test different functionality so I thought I'd build a function

```
const mockReactRouterDom = path => {
    jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
        ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
        useLocation: () => ({
            pathname: path,
        }),
    }))
}
```

however jest complained saying `babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of`jest.mock() `is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.`

so does anyone know how I can make this dynamic so that for different tests I can mock a different path?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options).

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export function usePageViews() {
  return useLocation();
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
const mockReactRouterDom = (path) => {
  jest.doMock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useLocation: () => ({
      pathname: path,
    }),
  }));
};

describe('64477184', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    mockReactRouterDom('/teresa-teng');
    const { usePageViews } = require('./');
    const actual = usePageViews();
    expect(actual).toEqual({ pathname: '/teresa-teng' });
  });
  it('should pass too', () => {
    mockReactRouterDom('/best-singers');
    const { usePageViews } = require('./');
    const actual = usePageViews();
    expect(actual).toEqual({ pathname: '/best-singers' });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64477184/index.test.ts
  64477184
    ✓ should pass (490ms)
    ✓ should pass too (5ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.003s, estimated 13s
```